# Cloudmade distance between two points

Tags: iphone, ios, cloudmade

I need to get the distance between two points without showing the map on a iPhone app. I'm trying to use CLoudMade ... but I can't figure it out from the documentation provided.
CAn anyone help me ... and make a little step-by-step tutorial or give me some pointers ?
Thank you

*i want to use CloudMade because i need the distance by following public roads. I know it's a stupid "question" but I really can't seem to get my head around this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this [post](http://support.cloudmade.com/forums/iphone-sdk/posts/1882/show) will be useful for you, you can get this info from route instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `-[CLLocation distanceFromLocation:]`?

Comment: sorry ... I need the distance by roads. frgot to mention that.